# Compare multi-property to value from traversal

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I have a graph where some nodes have a property, say ID, and all nodes have a multi-property "matches" that identifies IDs they are relevant for.

I want to create a query that travereses the valid tree from each of my nodes with ID.

```
g.addV().property("id","1").as("o").
  addV().property(set,"matches","1").property(set,"matches","2")
    .property(set,"matches","3").as("a")
  addV().property(set,"matches","2").property(set,"matches","3").as("b").
  addV().property(set,"matches","1").property(set,"matches","3").as("c").
  addE("link").from("o").to("a").
  addE("link").from("o").to("b").
  addE("link").from("a").to("c").
  addE("link").from("c").to("b")
```

In Java with tinkergraph 3.4.6 I had some success with this, but it fails when I try to wrap the out step in a repeat with `class java.util.UUID cannot be cast to class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element` (both id and matches entries are UUIDs)

```
g.V().has("id").as("from").values("id").as("i").select("from").out().where(properties("matches").value().as("i")
```

In gremlify I haven't had any success on selecting only the out vertices that match the original ID.

Comment: If one vertex matches a set of others why not create edges between that vertex and the others with a "MATCHES" label. If feels to me as if that will be a more "graph like" solution and make writing queries easier.

Comment: When I run your query using TinkerGraph / Gremlin Console 3.4.10 it seems to be working as expected as only one vertex with an 'ID' of 1 is connected to the 'o' vertex

Comment: I also rewrote the query a little and got the same results `gremlin> g.V().
......1>   has("id").as("from").
......2>   out().
......3>   where(eq("from")).
......4>     by(properties("matches").value()).
......5>     by('id')  
==>v[2]        `